# how to search that List<strings> contains all values of given arrays[] of string using stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of movie Objects that contains title, producers, directors, actors and release year. I need to find which movie is directed by given director(s). then store all found movies in a map using directors as key and movie titles as value. I came up with the following code but it is not finding any movie but actually data has several movies that are directed by given directors.

```
String directors = "Wes Craven,John Carpenter,Alfred Hitchcock";
String[] st = directors.split(",");

Map<String,List<String>> map =  data.stream()
                                .filter(movie -> movie.getDirectors().contains(st[0]) && movie.getDirectors().contains(st[1]) && movie.getDirectors().contains(st[2]))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Movie::getTitle),m-> m.getDirectors());

map.forEach((m,n) -> System.out.println(m+" : "+n));
```

Comment: can you share your input and the output that you get currently? (You probably meant using `||` for any director amongst st instead of using `&&` which would mean that all the elements of st should be a part of directors' collection in the movie object?)

Comment: input : List<String> conataining different names of directors According to movie.

Output : condition is becoming false everytime.

Comment: is there any way i can write Predicate<Movie> so can pass whole String and it check every list of directors and match to given names to directors ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Naman yup i changed the constant ```key``` to m.getTitle()

Comment: sorry for the wrong information that I gave... I actually changed my map to ```<title, directors> ``` after your suggestion

Comment: @ShivamPrajapati and what is `directors` there, a `List<String>`? Does that make the output to be of type `Map<String, List<String>>`? Did you try to write code to attain this? Please update the question with an edit to add complete information there.

Comment: On a different note, unless the order of directors really matter I would choose to represent the `Movie` class as `class Movie {
        String title;
        Set<String> directors;...}` and then perform a `containsAll` check in the `filter` predicate.

Comment: thanks, @Naman I changed the data type of directors and it works fine.

Comment: @ShivamPrajapati It should have worked with any type of collection that exposes a `contains` API to query an element's existence. I am pretty sure the question is not reproducible and hence voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to tell what is going wrong without additional information. However I suggest you do the following to resolve your issue:

1. Add a `hasDirector(String)` method to `Movie` that returns `true` if the movie has the given director
2. Add unit tests to make sure it works
3. Add a `hasAllDirectors(String[])` method to `Movie` that returns `true` if the movie has all the given directors
4. Add unit tests to make sure it works
5. Covert your code to `movieList.stream().filter(m -> m.hasAllDirectors(directorArray))` where `directoryArray` is a `String[]`
6. Add unit tests to make sure it works

Come back to this forum if it still doesn't work

Comment: I don’t think that `.filter(m -> m.hasAllDirectors(directors.split(",")))` is a good suggestion. This implies performing the work of splitting the string into an array of substrings each time, the predicate is evaluated. The OP was already better at this, by performing the work once at the beginning. Besides, `movie.getDirectors().containsAll(collection)` would do the job without the need to implement anything manually…

Comment: Fair point on your first suggestion - will make that change. I disagree on your second.